# ssh - keys and password

Tags: security, ssh, password, certificate

I've gotten keys (certificates) working correctly, but as it is, it's more of a "convenience" thing. (which I love). But as far as security, someone can still use a password to login. What's a good way to disable passwords and only allow certificate logins? I don't want to just choose a random password (which would probably work also), but I want to disable passwords entirely.

Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit your sshd_config (likely /etc/ssh/sshd_config, but varies) and change this:

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

To this:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

To make it live you will need to restart your sshd daemon.

For more generally useful sshd configuration information you can run the following:

```
man sshd_config
```

Answer (score 0):

What Neil said is correct, but you can also do `usermod -L username` to disable a user's password, but not his key login. This puts a "!" in front of the hash in /etc/shadow. Public key auth still works when you do that.

Comment: There are other implications of this however - if your account is locked via `usermod -L`, then the user cannot sudo. Disabling password authentication via SSH is generally a better approach as well, as you don't need to remember to lock any new accounts you create.